# executing an app from eclispe onto HTC Hero

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, device

I've come to a point in my development where it's about time I test the app on an actual device and so I a trying to do that on my old HTC Hero.

I've followed the instructions on the developers website for android at this link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html  and everytime I go to 'Run' the app it tells me there is "No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD."

When I look at the setup of the app it's configured for Android 2.1 (api 7) and the HTC Hero is Android 2.1 (update-1). I have gone into settings>Applications>Development on the phone and set it to allow debugging through USB.

Therefore I am really struggling to find out how to fix this.

Comment: The necessary PC setup details will depend on your PC operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the phone is set to file mode (e.g. you can open it as if it were another disk drive). Some modes can prevent adb from picking it up. If it were a version problem, Eclipse would say that, it wouldn't just not show any device.

To rule out it being a config issue in eclipse, you should be able to call 'adb logcat' in command line (find adb in your android-sdk directory under platform-tools/adb.exe) and it should spit out the log for your phone (and not say something like 'waiting for device').

Finally, you may need specific drivers for some phones (e.g. HTC Sync). If you're on linux, you can setup udev rules for it http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up

Comment: 'adb devices' is a more appropriate command, in particular it behaves more usefully when multiple devices (including emulators) are connected.

Comment: Thanks guys that really helped. I did find another problem, my HTC Hero doesn't get recognised when I'm on my new laptop even with HTC Sync setup, so I am using my older one and your advice got it working for me on there.